# Cassette tape to MP3 converter to not writing as expected to a USB flash drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

I'm having trouble getting my cassette tape to MP3 converter to record on a USB flash drive.

Could the USB flash I’m using be too big (It’s only 8GB, but it’s an older unit), or did I set the Allocation Unit Size (AUS) incorrectly when I reformatted the USB flash drive as exFAT? I chose 4K.

Answer (score 2):

> “I reformatted the USB flash drive as exFAT?”

Most likely you ned to format it as FAT32 with MBR (Master Boot Record) partitioning if you have that option. The reason being is these simple — and they tend to be — audio devices that use USB flash drives for storage don’t have particularly robust data controllers. FAT32 is the format pretty much all USB flash drives are formatted with by default. So do that and you should be solid.